# Spring Cloud Dataflow Application Properties to Show a dropdown in Dataflow Ui

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to know how to specify a property here so that i can get a dropdown in Spring Cloud Dataflow ui when ill register my app. I am adding screeshot of my app modal

[image: this is my modal]

This is the property file of my app

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import java.util.*;

@ConfigurationProperties("filestream")
public class FileStreamProperties {

/* filePath for file stream */
private String filePath;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>().add("option1");
/* delayMillis the delay between checks of the file for new content in milliseconds */
private long delayMillis = 1000;

private long bufferSize = 4096;
private Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();


public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

public long getDelayMillis() {
    return delayMillis;
}

public void setDelayMillis(long delayMillis) {
    this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
}

public long getBufferSize() {
    return bufferSize;
}

public void setBufferSize(long bufferSize) {
    this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
}

public Charset getCharset() {
    return charset;
}

public void setCharset(Charset charset) {
    this.charset = charset;
}
```

}

Comment: We do not have OOTB support for dropdowns except the `scrtiptable-transform` processor - there's something specifically hard coded in the UI for this. It is also interesting that you have a partially rendering UI fragment in your screenshot. 

If you can clarify on what you have done to render that, we can take it from there. Can you also share your custom application's GH repo? 

Perhaps you could contribute back to the project as well.

Comment: Hi apart from this issue i want to ask you is there any way to implement user authentication using database ?